# SOQL query WHERE Date = 30_days_ago?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

How do I make a SOQL query like this?

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate = 30_DAYS_AGO
```

This produces an error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
Account WHERE LastActivityDate = 30_DAYS_AGO
                      ^
```

Comment: Are you executing this query in a web service call or in Apex code?  superfell's answer is correct if this is in Apex.

Comment: Via a webservice, but I just declared the date in the program and passed it as a string to the query as a specific date.

Comment: I assumed you were using apex, as you tagged the question with apex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you're doing this from apex, you can calculate the date in apex, then bind that into your query, e.g.

```
date d = system.today().addDays(-30);
Account [] acc=  [select id from account where createdDate = :d];
```

Comment: LAST_N_DAYS would be a better approach since SOQL already has a syntax to do this, or maybe they added it later?

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30
```

Comment: This would be inclusive of all 30 days, OP only wanted the last activity from one day.

Answer (score 9):

```
Select Id from Account Where LastActivityDate = N_DAYS_AGO:30
```

Answer (score 1):

`LAST_WEEK` and `LAST_MONTH` are also easy and work well.

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate > LAST_MONTH
```

For more data look at this link: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Answer (score 0):

The page of SOQL date functions appears to have moved here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

To clarify, SOQL allows a date field (e.g. LastActivityDate) to be compared against a range of dates using a comparison operator. So "LastActivityDate = LAST_MONTH" is equivalent to saying that the date is greater than or equal to the start of the first day of the previous month AND less than or equal to the end of the last day.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is 30 days ago, you an use this -

```
SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30
```

Comment: I don't think LAST_N_DAYS works with the '<' operator. I think it only works with =

Comment: We are using it with '<' operator currently.  https://getblogname.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/soql-last_n_days-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

Your query time period  lies in the Date literals provided SFDC its best to use
it as the time specified is a broad number , , you just need to provide the no of days and accordingly use the  operator which is '=' ,'>' or '<'

```
LAST_N_DAYS:n       LAST_N_WEEKS:n      LAST_N_MONTHS:n     LAST_N_YEAR:n

NEXT_N_DAYS:n       NEXT_N_WEEKS:n      NEXT_N_MONTHS:n     NEXT_N_YEAR:n
```

your query would look simpler if you just provided the no of days / month which
it falls in .

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:1
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30
```

Thanks,
OQ.